# Receiving HTTP transport error : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, jax-ws, pkcs#12

I am implementing a jax-ws web service client in a maven sub module using **jaxws-maven-plugin** with **wsimport** goal, which is in charge of parsing multiple configured .wsdl files in order to generate the needed artifacts to code the client.

The generation process is working fine, but when implementing the client, I need to use SSL when communicating with the deployed web service. For that, the client provided me with a certificate (**cert.p12** file) and a password .

As I don't have access to the HttpsURLConnection to initialize the SSLContext programatically when using the jax-ws generated artifacts to implement the web service client, I've just coded an *initProxySettings()* method which will be in charge of setting system properties before calling the client as shown below.

```
private void initProxySettings() {
        Properties systemSettings = System.getProperties();

        systemSettings.setProperty("proxySet", "true");
        systemSettings.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
        systemSettings.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "443");
        systemSettings.setProperty("https.proxyHost", sslProxyHost);
        systemSettings.setProperty("https.proxyPort", sslProxyPort);

        systemSettings.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", p12FilePath); 
        systemSettings.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",p12FilePassword); 
        systemSettings.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12"); 
        systemSettings.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl"); 

        System.setProperties(systemSettings);
    }
```

When trying to run a connected test with the service, I get the following error :

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:121)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at $Proxy95.reportRatesTrade(Unknown Source)
    at myCompany.connectivity.myApp.wsconnector.FpmlReportSender.sendRateFpmlReport(FpmlReportSender.java:66)
    at myCompany.connectivity.myAPP.wsconnector.FpmlWsClientSender.sendFpmlViaWebService(FpmlWsClientSender.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:407)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:278)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:251)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:401)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:165)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1623)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:198)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:192)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1074)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:128)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:465)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1120)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1147)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1131)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:904)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:109)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:325)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:219)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1053)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:320)
    ... 61 more
```

Here is an excerpt of the SSL debug which I've shorten :

```
keyStore type is : pkcs12
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
***
found key for : company- mail@mail.com
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=company99DF011B-51A9-57F9-E341-E0A68D4B9751, OU=USERS, O=KGC0418
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  SunPKCS11-Solaris RSA public key, 2048 bits (id 139309464, session object)
  modulus: 22112756093157512458757695440781457752806273315592450355957740196952202759592017766120571999875831031807562268295134910443622272782776544232874456458580772402436337356828895708779249509298037562892132455656130873883482145964182231114271360652011365917415253840206676718726431817484730833855366587344152579527243740623
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sun Dec 08 17:31:09 MET 2013,
               To: Thu Jan 08 17:31:09 MET 2015]
  Issuer: CN=KGC0418 companyPROD, OU=company Authorized Use Only, O=KGC0418, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    03]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.1 Criticality=false
NetscapeCertType [
   SSL client
   S/MIME
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 1A C2 D9 E5 AC 6D 36 2F   65 F1 4C A2 11 3B 92 EB  .....m6/e.L..;..
0010: 9B F9 4B CA                                        ..K.
]

[CN=company Global Root CA, OU=company Authorized Use Only, O=COMPANY, C=US]
SerialNumber: [    14]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:....
.........
......
.....
.....
***
trustStore is: /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
.........
........
.........
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1373450395 bytes = { 223, 37, 1, 148, 219, 69, 149, 109, 169, 194, 44, 197, 99, 80, 16, 189, 197, 104, 28, 99, 157, 172, 34, 240, 145, 73, 49, 89 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
Camel (myApp) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 73
Camel (myApp) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 98
Camel (myApp) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 74
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1373446593 bytes = { 83, 8, 141, 30, 34, 196, 26, 7, 232, 255, 119, 56, 80, 5, 201, 181, 68, 107, 17, 160, 109, 152, 79, 219, 19, 16, 181, 222 }
Session ID:  {146, 198, 54, 212, 84, 229, 79, 190, 99, 152, 78, 98, 18, 19, 152, 253, 197, 212, 1, 37, 17, 33, 77, 113, 59, 86, 136, 120, 33, 19, 126, 1}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Compression Method: 0
***
%% Created:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
** SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Camel (myApp) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1295
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[....
.....
.....
.....
[9]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:...
....
...
]
***
Camel (myApp) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
Camel (myApp) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
Camel (myApp) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, called closeSocket()
Camel (myApp) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
```

Could you tell me if this is the right way to use a .p12 certificate with JAX-WS client ? If my implementation is meaningful, what am I missing then ?

------ **UPDATE** -------

As suggested by @Jcs in the next post I've created a custom new key store in a JKS format by the following steps :

1/ Extracting the public key from cert.p12 file using the command :

```
openssl.exe pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out publicCert.pem
```

2/ Creating a new trust store in JKS format using :

```
keytool -import -alias test -file publicCert.pem -keystore myTrustStore.jks
```

Then keeping the same configuration for the keyStore, I've configured the trusStore properties to point out this new generated JKS store as follows :

```
systemSettings.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", myTrustStore.jks);
systemSettings.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", jksFilePassword);
systemSettings.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
/*****/
systemSettings.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", cert.p12); 
systemSettings.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", p12FilePassword); 
systemSettings.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
```

Now from what I see in the ssl.debug console, the trustStore points at the one I've set in my implementation :

```
***
trustStore is: src\test\resources\certificate\myTrustStore.jks
trustStore type is : JKS
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=COMPANY 99DF011B-51A9-57F9-E341-E0A68D4B9751, OU=USERS, O=KGC0418
  Issuer:  CN=KGC0418 XXXXXXXXX
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x3
  Valid from Sun Dec 08 17:31:09 GMT+01:00 2013 until Thu Jan 08 17:31:09 GMT+01:00 2015

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1373559519 bytes = { 73, 210, 46, 42, 251, 113, 112, 255, 135, 100, 241, 240, 245, 125, 197, 72, 118, 72, 226, 121, 151, 222, 36, 76, 69, 108, 59, 223 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
Camel (camel-2) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 73
Camel (camel-2) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 98
Camel (camel-2) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 74
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1373559520 bytes = { 208, 198, 151, 119, 235, 39, 193, 62, 48, 230, 205, 106, 86, 238, 78, 91, 82, 255, 187, 234, 12, 5, 121, 49, 30, 109, 211, 209 }
Session ID:  {6, 28, 249, 26, 112, 151, 19, 203, 2, 16, 79, 111, 188, 253, 24, 4, 247, 139, 66, 144, 210, 30, 101, 226, 40, 73, 228, 161, 55, 230, 221, 114}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Compression Method: 0
***
%% Created:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
** SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Camel (camel-2) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1295
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=xxxxxxxxxxxx
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 26518340377185970618433427871998795874305944949774222457599695023228997443108630011833718821919400987851754545189639992819856454324827540671299918071626122667103792561945932972886083246760975456684092491592159887675835743379582226715892057387136711529603424019350987371140627696296825793550900188321364783977163343619847560039629745177775488269466101953205609461762679291911956872358518707250384413293488030799581673273259857148207483603504965811669522407902645141827155299400058670101699158958543405382995894352227209548308584112363108195961049506258872806165116902528885827281882201616114758666943336739405701681289
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Nov 07 12:56:30 GMT+01:00 2013,
               To: Sat Jan 09 18:53:11 GMT+01:00 2016]
  Issuer: CN=GeoTrust SSL CA, O="GeoTrust, Inc.", C=US
  SerialNumber: [    02a093]

Certificate Extensions: 9
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1
   accessLocation: URIName: http://gtssl-ocsp.geotrust.com, 
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2
   accessLocation: URIName: http://gtssl-aia.geotrust.com/gtssl.crt]
]
....
[2]: ObjectId: 2.xx.xx.17 Criticality=false
....
[3]: ObjectId: 2.xx.xx.35 Criticality=false
...
[4]: ObjectId: 2.xx.xx.14 Criticality=false
....
[5]: ObjectId: 2.xx.xx.32 Criticality=false
....
[6]: ObjectId: 2.xx.xx.19 Criticality=true
....
[7]: ObjectId: 2.xx.xx.37 Criticality=false
....
[8]: ObjectId: 2.xx.xx.31 Criticality=false
..
.
[9]: ObjectId: 2.xx.xx.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 14 EB 1F A8 91 DE F0 A6   54 B4 BB D1 6F E4 10 63  ........T...o..c

]
***
Camel (camel-2) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
Camel (camel-2) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
Camel (camel-2) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, called closeSocket()
Camel (camel-2) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Camel (camel-2) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, called close()
Camel (camel-2) thread #0 - file://src/test/resources/fpml, called closeInternal(true)
```

but I'm still having the same error :

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:121)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at $Proxy102.reportRatesTrade(Unknown Source)
    at myCompany.connectivity.myApp.wsconnector.FpmlReportSender.sendRateFpmlReport(FpmlReportSender.java:75)
    at myCompany.connectivity.myApp.wsconnector.FpmlWsClientSender.sendFpmlViaWebService(FpmlWsClientSender.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:407)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:278)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:251)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:401)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:165)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1623)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:198)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:192)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1074)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:128)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:465)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1120)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1147)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1131)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:904)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:109)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:294)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:200)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1053)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:289)
    ... 61 more
```

Did I set both the keyStore and the trustStore correctly ?

Comment: You add as trusted certificate with `Issuer:  CN=KGC0418 XXXXXXXXX`, and server uses certifiace with `Issuer: CN=GeoTrust SSL CA`. Try to add right certificate (Issuer: CN=GeoTrust SSL CA, O="GeoTrust, Inc.", C=US) to truststore.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I see, you are correctly using the PKCS#12 file. The problem is caused by the server certificate. Since you did not set any `trustStore` the default `trustStore` is used. This is written in this log line:

```
trustStore is: /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

However SSL implementation was not able to attach the server certificate chain to any trusted certificate in this store. Maybe this server certificate is self-signed, maybe it is issued by a dedicated in-house certification authority or maybe it has just been issued by a certification authority which is not listed here.

To fix it, ask your client for the root CA certificate and add it into the `cacerts` file or create a custom new keystore. You can use the `keytool -importcert` command.

If you create a new keystore, you'll need to add this to your code:

```
systemSettings.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/to/trust/store"); 
systemSettings.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "trustStorePassword");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, from what I understood, I have two choices : whether I import the root CA that my client will provide me in the default cacerts file under .../jre/lib/security/cacerts, or I should create a new keystore which I'll set as a trsutStore which I guess is a JKS file describing a public key (In this case, should I be using the original .p12 file my client first sent me ?) Thanks

Comment: Yes, these are your 2 choices. I do not think the .p12 contains the root certificate (even if it is worth to verify). To my understanding this p12 file contains the key and certificate required for the client authentication when using the web service.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Jcs, I've generated a JKS file from the .p12 certificate and et it as a new trustStore in my implementation. I'm now pointing at the new trustStore but stille have the same exception. **I've edited my post to track the changes you mentioned**

Comment: Sorry, I think I was unclear on that point: the trust store must contains the certificate of the root certification authority which issued the server SSL certificate, *not your own certificate* (in the p12 file). Moreover there is no reason why your certificate and the server certificate are signed by the same authority.

Comment: Yes, I've changed my strategy by importing the certificate from its URL using the browser into the default cacerts store under my JDK installation (I've listed cacerts certificates and found that the needed certificate was successfully imported), then I managed to use cacerts as default trustStore instead of a custom key store, and kept the property `systemSettings.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "cert.p12");` to use the **cert.p12** file as the keyStore. At the end  unfortunately, I'm always facing the same error